# Global variable from other module broke karma tests for angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, gruntjs, karma-runner

Given two angular modules: `module1` and `module2`.

`module1` in its controller declare global variable:

```
window.__ = function() {
    // code
}
```

I have own reasons to make it global (instead of putting it to $rootScope or something else).

`module2` uses this global variable.

My problem is when I testing `module2` with karma it throws error that `__` variable is undefined. How can avoid it?

Comment: have the same issue. $rootScope.__global from MainCtrl showing data in Header Ctrl but fail tests